# How do you mark a prop as required in react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to mark a prop as a required prop in a react typescript application, how can I do that?
Using react with js, one chains `isRequired` keyword on the type. How can i do this with ts?

```
// Here is my typescript code:

interface Props {
  /** Message to display */
  message: string;
}

const defaultProps: Props = {
  message: 'World',
};
/** My first reusable component */
function HelloWorld({ message }: Props) {
  return <div>Hello {message}</div>;
}

HelloWorld.defaultProps = defaultProps;
```

Here is the jsx I am trying to reproduce

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function HelloWorld({message}) {
  return <div>Hello {message}</div>
}

HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string.required
};

HelloWorld.defaultProps = {
  message: 'World'
};

export default HelloWorld;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to explicitly specify output type for `HelloWorld` function

```
function HelloWorld({ message }: Props): React.SFC<Props> {
  return <div>Hello {message}</div>;
}
```

or

```
const HelloWorld: React.SFC<Props> = ({ message }) => {
  return <div>Hello {message}</div>;
}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, I don't know what SFC is but let me look it up now

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean? If you define an interface without optional fields, all of them are required by default? Yout don't need extra type checking.

Comment: This was exactly thinking btw, I was however not sure. Seeing that you share the same thinking, I will take that I have marked the prop as required by not making it optional in the interface

Comment: Józef is actually right. you need to hand over a `React.SFC<Props>` return type.

Comment: Don't know what SFC is but I am going to look it up

Comment: @ChrisPi you are right, but no error is raised. Only text editor shows error about missing props but the app works fine. How can we raise error when some prop is missing